# how do i vertical scroll to an element using a nice animation effect with jquery?

Tags: jquery

How do i vertical scroll to an element using a nice animation effect with jquery?

i have an alphabet menu like this:

```
<ul id="alphabet">
   <li><a href="#A">A</a></li>
   <li><a href="#B">B</a></li>
   <li><a href="#C">C</a></li>
   <li><a href="#D">D</a></li>
   <li><a href="#E">E</a></li>
</ul>
```

i have another list with a min-height of 1000px and overflow:auto

```
<ul id="list">
<li id="A">...</li>
<li id="B">...</li>
<li id="C">...</li>
<li id="D">...</li>
</ul>
```

by the way, the sample list above looks short, but the real one is very large....

if i click on the first list, let's say C, i then want to go to the li in the second list  with an id of C, using an animated effect... if a click A on the first list, then i want to go to A in the second list... and so on... In other words, i will be going up and down the second list

this is so far my code in jquery

```
// goto item in list
$('#alphabet a').click(function(e) {
   var clicked = $(this).attr('href').slice(1);

   //goto element in list using a nice animation effect

   $('ul#list').animate({
    ????
   }, 400);
});
```

i need help finishing my code in jquery

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following , hope it shall serve your purpose.[ScrollTo Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo)

Comment: i forgot to mention on my initial post that i'm not looking for a plugin...after all, it's probably less then 10 lines of code... Still, thanks for the link

Comment: something like this , you wanna try               jQuery('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: (parseFloat(jQuery("#Commentfocus").offset().top) - 500) }, 0);

Comment: what is #Commentfocus in relation to my sample... and what about the 500? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery scrollTo plugin for the same http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo

Comment: i forgot to mention on my initial post that i'm not looking for a plugin...after all, it's probably less then 10 lines of code... Still, thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

i believe i've found the answer... this works very elegantly...

```
function scrollTo(ele1, ele2, id) { 
    var a = $(ele1).offset().top;
    var b = $(ele2+'[id='+id+']').offset().top;
    var pos = b - a;

    $(ele1).animate({
        scrollTop: '+=' + pos + 'px'
    }, 400);
}

// jQuery
$('#alphabet a').click(function(e) {
    var clicked = $(this).attr('href').slice(1);

    scrollTo('ul#list', 'ul#list li', clicked);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

PLEASE feel free to optimize the code!

Thansk for all the tips and guidance
Marco

Comment: just read about a better way to get the hash: var clicked = this.hash.slice(1);